# SQL Separate tables joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT COUNT(sa.SessionId) AS AttendancePoints, sa.UserId 
FROM SessionAttendance sa 
WHERE IsParticipated = 1 
GROUP BY UserId

SELECT COUNT(sf.Session_Id) AS FeedbackPoints, sf.User_Id 
FROM SessionFeedbacks sf 
GROUP BY User_Id

SELECT SUM(sac.Points) AS ActivityPoints, sac.UserId 
FROM StudentActivities sac 
GROUP BY UserId
```

[Sample OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi6bu.png)

Is there any way to put those 3 outputs into single output using a common user id in SQL Server?

Required Output:

```
User Id | AttendancePoints | FeedbackPoints | ActivityPoints
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.   Your question is not clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "join" - join is a SQL keyword and with a specific meaning. Are you wanting to join them? Or to combine the resultsets? Sample data and desired results are required as Gordon has asked for.

Comment: @DaleK join means I need to put those 3 table into single table

Comment: @SanjanaSulakshana but vertically or horizontally? We need an example of how your data should look.

Comment: @DaleK Sample output attached. I want to combine those 3 outputs into a single output using that common user id column.

Comment: BTW: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pop them in a sub-query e.g.

```
SELECT AttendancePoints, UserId
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(sa.SessionId) AS AttendancePoints, sa.UserId 
    FROM SessionAttendance sa 
    WHERE IsParticipated = 1 
    GROUP BY UserId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT COUNT(sf.Session_Id) AS FeedbackPoints, sf.User_Id 
    FROM SessionFeedbacks sf 
    GROUP BY User_Id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(sac.Points) AS ActivityPoints, sac.UserId 
    FROM StudentActivities sac 
    GROUP BY UserId
) X
```

Comment: It's Woking. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

- You can use union to join them all into 1
- to keep the differentiation you can create category

```
with combining_points as (
    SELECT COUNT(sa.SessionId) AS AttendancePoints, sa.UserId, 'AttendancePoints' as category
    FROM SessionAttendance sa WHERE IsParticipated = 1 GROUP BY UserId

    union all

    SELECT COUNT(sf.Session_Id) AS FeedbackPoints, sf.User_Id , 'FeedbackScore' as category
    FROM SessionFeedbacks sf GROUP BY User_Id
    union all

    SELECT SUM(sac.Points) AS ActivityPoints, sac.UserId, 'ActivityPoints' as category
    FROM StudentActivities sac GROUP BY UserId
)

select * from combining_points
```

Comment: MSSMS Says , 
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Invalid column name 'category'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'category'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'category'.

Comment: @trillion you can't group by a table alias.

Comment: @SanjanaSulakshana try again

Comment: @SanjanaSulakshana I have adjusted

Comment: @trillion It's not providing the required output. Question Updated!

Comment: @SanjanaSulakshana try again

Answer (score 0):

```
with BeginCTE as(
SELECT COUNT(sa.SessionId) AS AttendancePoints, sa.UserId 
FROM SessionAttendance sa 
WHERE IsParticipated = 1 
GROUP BY UserId
),
MiddleCTE as
(
SELECT COUNT(sf.Session_Id) AS FeedbackPoints, sf.UserId 
FROM SessionFeedbacks sf 
GROUP BY UserId
),
EndCTE as
(
SELECT SUM(sac.Points) AS ActivityPoints, sac.UserId 
FROM StudentActivities sac 
GROUP BY UserId
)
select a.UserID,a.AttendancePoints,b.FeedbackPoints,c.ActivityPoints from 
BeginCTE a
INNER JOIN MiddleCTE b ON a.UserId=b.UserId
INNER JOIN EndCTE c ON b.UserId=c.UserId
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.